# jQuery stopPropagation not working

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I'm using the following [color picker](https://github.com/meta100/mColorPicker/blob/master/javascripts/mColorPicker.js) and it works fine, but when i click on the color picker icon, i don't want it to bubble to body. So i tried the following and now the color picker is not working.

**Check http://jsfiddle.net/CWGgM/**.

If you remove the below code from jsfiddle then it works. What is causing this

```
$('#test').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Did you link to the correct fiddle?

Comment: @alex oops. Fixed. It's http://jsfiddle.net/CWGgM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to use its own [`live()` style code](https://github.com/meta100/mColorPicker/blob/master/javascripts/mColorPicker.js#L96), where events are allowed to bubble up and are handled on the `document`.

Therefore, the events must propagate to `document` or they won't work.

You could avoid the event triggering on body with the following workaround...

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).parent()[0] == $('.mColorPickerTrigger')[0]) {
       return true;   
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/GEN3J/).

Or this might work better with multiple color pickers...

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).parent().hasClass('mColorPickerTrigger')) {
       return true;   
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/GEN3J/1/).

Comment: Thanks, this works for the specific case of the icon, but it want everything inside the div #test to not bubble to body, that's why i have the wrapper #test. Is this still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Like @alex mentioned it, the color picker seems to be listening clicks on the whole document using `live()`. Before blocking the propagation, you can check if the event originated from the color picker, and let it bubble up if it did. You need to use `closest()`, because it's possible to click either on the color picker icon's `<span>` container or the `<img>` element inside.

```
$('#test').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('.mColorPickerTrigger').length) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Check out the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CWGgM/1/

Comment: Yes, but the way you have it, it still bubbles up to body. I believe since the colors picker was made to use document, then there no real way to fix this issue.

Comment: My solution blocks **everything, but** the color picker's click event, why is that a problem? It's actually a similar solution to the one you accepted, except this works even if you click the `<span>` next to the icon, and I couldn't get any of the accepted answers to work if you enable the `stopPropagation()` lines, which is what you wanted to do in the first place. In my example, everything else stops propagating *on the div*, the blocked alert is not on the body, but before you call `stopPropagation()`, which actually works.

Comment: your solution still bubbles up to body which is not what i want. Check http://jsfiddle.net/CWGgM/2/

Comment: Ok, I see now you just wanted the icon click not to bubble up, whatever the reason might be. ;)